# Should the information link in Teams have javascript:void(0)?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, sidebar

I noticed in the sidebar the information link of Teams has the destination `javascript:void(0)`. Should it read like that? It seems there could be a prettier text.

Reference: [Don't use the <a> HTML element for things which aren't hyperlinks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286894/665544)

[image: screenshot of temas info icon in sidebar]

Comment: It could definitely be made a button rather than an anchor/ link, but what you're referring to isn't a caption, it's the link's destination. That hint at the bottom left appears every time you hover over a link on desktop. I think the only way to fix this would be to make that element something other than an anchor `<a>`.

Comment: @zcoop98 thanks for pointing out my incorrect use of the word caption. I used it as an alias that just came to mind.

Comment: We can't fix browsers, call Google instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could perhaps link directly to `https://stackoverflow.com/teams`, which is the target for the "learn more" link in the little JavaScript popup that results when you click the `(i)` link (when JS is enabled).

This would give a more meaningful link target and allow the link to "work" when JS is not available, but would still be overridden (to display the little popup) when JS is available.

[image: Teams popup - learn more link]